# Получение данных из JSON в Android

Tags: java, android, json, wcf

Я делаю небольшое тестовое приложение на Android, которое бы получало данные из WCF-сервиса, читало их и выводило на экран.
Я сделал WCF, которое преобразует элементы списка(List) в json-строку такого вида:

```
"[{\"LastName\":\"Baggins\",\"FirstName\":\"Frodo\",\"Street\":\"Bagshot Row\"}, 
{\"LastName\":\"Kurata\",\"FirstName\":\"Deborah\",\"Street\":\"Main Street\"}]"
```

И у меня вопрос - как данную строку в Android-клиенте правильно парсить, и из них создать свой список, аналогичный списку на c#, для использования, допустим, в `ListView? 
С Java очень плохо знаком, и еще не знаю большинства его функции.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем в проект Jackson.

Дальше уже как захотим. Если объекты в массиве всегда одинаковой структуры, то лучше создать класс типо такого:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("LastName")
    public String mLastName;

    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    public String mFirstName;

    @JsonProperty("Street")
    public String mStreet;
}
```

Парсить так:

```
String jsonString = // здесь ваша строка с данными
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
    new TypeReference<ArrayList<Person>>() {});
```

Теперь в `mapper` у вас список объектов.

Comment: Я добавил Jackson в проект, но программа выделяет new TypeReference<ArrayList<Person>>() {}); - cannot resolve simbol TypeReference

Comment: @lcnw импорты то прописали? `import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;`

Comment: прописал, и все равно ругается на TypeReference, теперь еще и в импорте: import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

Comment: @lcnw вы как подключили либу? Точно этот артефакт? `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>` ?